# module 'keras.layers' has no attribute 'experimental'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset

hello so I was trying to resize and rescale my dataset as shown below l but I encountered this error:

AttributeError: module 'keras.layers' has no attribute 'experimental'

```
resize_and_rescale= tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.Resizing(IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1.0/255)
])
```

Answer (score 1):

actually I tried adding "tf.keras" in front of my layers line and it worked :

```
resize_and_rescale= tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Resizing(IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE),
tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1.0/255)])
```

thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if it worked by adding tf.keras.layers, even though you have already imported Keras from TensorFlow earlier, then it is most likely an issue with the importation chain of the libraries rather than the actual block of code. Cross-check how you imported the libraries earlier to reduce redundant importing as you might have done now. Also, this will make your code cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
resize_and_rescale = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.Resizing(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
    layers.Rescaling(1./255),
])
```